# How to send some additional app info when user sends email using MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is there any way to make my app send to me some additional app info when user sends an email from inside my app using MFMailComposeViewController but without enabling the user to delete or change that info? For example, I would like to receive with every user email some info like what is the device user is using, or number that shows how many times user launched my app, etc., but I don't want the user to have the option of changing or deleting that info in email. Is there maybe some other way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public key encrypted attachment with the info you want to send.

Comment: Well, this is interesting idea. There is no simpler way?

Comment: I can't think of any that is not alterable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using email to gather feedback from your user, we have a feedback form that you can add to your app instead. Along with the user name, email, and comments, we do include information like device type and os version (the user doesn't see this).  The form background color can match your app's color theme.  Some developers have asked for that customization.  You'll also get to specify feedback types and categories.  This lets the user self classify the feedback.  For example, feedback types can be "suggestions," "bugs," "testimonials," and "questions."  Categories are sub types, which allows for narrowing down the feedback being given.  You define the types and categories.  The user chooses them while filling out the feedback form. All the feedback is sent to our feedback center for you to view, sort, respond, set status, group, and manage.  You can be notified by email when feedback arrives.

Learn more at: [www.SimpleFeedback.com - iOS Feedback](http://www.simplefeedback.com/learn/ios.cfm)